# Type Error： WCS.slice() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

Tags: radio-astronomy

My code：

```
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from astropy.io import fits
from reproject import reproject_interp
from reproject.mosaicking import reproject_and_coadd
from astropy.wcs import WCS
from spectral_cube import SpectralCube as sc
hdu = fits.open('/media/ljy/PS2000/TEST/GALFA_HI_RA+DEC_004.00+10.35_N.fits')[0]
wcs1 = WCS(hdu.header)
wcs2d = wcs1.slice(slice(None), slice(None), 0)
wcs2d
```

The Error:---------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[6], line 3
      1 hdu = fits.open('/media/ljy/PS2000/TEST/GALFA_HI_RA+DEC_004.00+10.35_N.fits')[0]
      2 wcs1 = WCS(hdu.header)
----> 3 wcs2d = wcs1.slice(slice(None), slice(None), 0)
      4 wcs2d

TypeError: WCS.slice() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

about the wcs.slice function,i try again and again.But it does not work.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best option is to just change line 3 to:

```
wcs2d = wcs1[:, :, 0]
```

But if you really want to use [`astropy.wcs.WCS.slice()`](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.wcs.WCS.html#astropy.wcs.WCS.slice) you need to change the argument to a tuple

```
wcs2d = wcs1.slice((slice(None), slice(None), 0))
```